# How to display overlay text on hover over the div and hide current text on the div in html and css

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions

I have one problem I have div in which I am showing overlay text and on div, I already have text on the main div I want to hide that existing text and show the other text which I have assigned as **display:none** when I hove on it.

I have created following HTML skeleton and I have applied CSS on it but I want on hover over the parent div I want content inside div **movies_post_text** should be hidden and the content inside div **movie-info** should be shown with CSS transitions

here it what i have tried

```js
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".movie-grid").on('hover',function(){
             $(".movies_post_text").css("display":"none");
             $(".movies_post_text").css("display":"block");
          });
      });
```

```css
   .movie-grid
    {
        background-image: url("img_avatar.png");
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 cursor:pointer;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    .hover-text
    {
        display:none;
    }
    
    .movies_post_text
    {
     right: 0;
        text-align: right;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 6;
        display: block;
        transition: all 300ms;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        padding: 10px 15px;
    }
    

    .hover-text  {
        text-align: right;
        bottom: -50px;
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
        max-height: 150px;
        overflow: hidden;
     }

    .movie-info
    {
     width:100%;
    }

    .movie-desc
    {
    float:right;
       width:66.66%;
    }

    .reactions
    {
    float:left;
       width:33.33%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="movie-grid movie-content">
    <a href="http://www.cricbuzz.com">
    
    <div class="movies_post_text overlay">
     <div class="post-title">INCIDENT BY A BANK</div>
     <div class="post-meta ">Sweden/12 MIN</div>
     <div class="post-meta">Award Winning, Drama, Thriller</div>
     <div class="post-meta ">DIR.Ruben Ostlund</div>
    </div>
                
    <div class="grid-text-wrap hover-text">
                 <div class="movie-info">

     <div class="movie-desc">
      <h3 class="grid-title">INCIDENT BY A BANK</h3>
      <p>Shot using a single camera, 90 people meticulously recreate a failed bank robbery that took place in Stockholm in June 2006. A superb single shot.The short went on to win the Golden Bear at </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="reactions">
      <span>429<i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
      <span class="">252<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></span>
     </div>
                    </div>
    </div>
    
    </a>
     </div>
```

Please help me to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Please Add this script and remove your css for hide/show div.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script><script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hover-text').hide();
   $('.movie-grid').hover(
     function () {
        $('.movies_post_text').hide();
        $('.hover-text').show();
     }, 
     function () {
        $('.movies_post_text').show();
        $('.hover-text').hide();
     }
  );
});
</script>
```